# 0.0 and -0.0 in Java (IEEE 754)

Tags: java, floating-point, ieee-754

Java is totally compatible with IEEE 754 right? But I'm confused about how java decide the sign of float point addition and substraction.

Here is my test result：

```
double a = -1.5;
double b = 0.0;
double c = -0.0;
System.out.println(b * a);  //-0.0
System.out.println(c * a);  //0.0
System.out.println(b + b);  //0.0
System.out.println(c + b);  //0.0
System.out.println(b + c);  //0.0
System.out.println(b - c);  //0.0
System.out.println(c - b);  //-0.0
System.out.println(c + c);  //-0.0
```

I think in the multiplication and division, the sign is decided like: sign(a) xor sign(b), 
but I wonder why 0.0 + -0.0 = 0.0, how does Java decide the sign in addition and substraction? Is it described in IEEE 754?

Also I found Java can somehow distinguish the similarities between 0.0 and -0.0, since

```
System.out.println(c == b);    //true
System.out.println(b == c);    //true
```

How does "==" in java works?
Is it treated as a special case?

Comment: 0.0 == -0.0 isn't a specificity of Java : it's specified by IEEE754

Comment: If you want chapter and verse, see section 6.3 of IEEE 754: "When the sum of two operands with opposite signs (or the difference of two operands with like signs) is exactly zero, the sign of that sum (or difference) shall be +0 in all rounding-direction attributes except roundTowardNegative; under that attribute, the sign of an exact zero sum (or difference) shall be -0."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's nothing here specific to Java, it's specified by IEEE754.

From [the wikipedia article on the negative zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) :

> According to the IEEE 754 standard, negative zero and positive zero
>   should compare as equal with the usual (numerical) comparison
>   operators, like the == operators of C and Java.

So the following numbers compare equal:

```
(+0) - (-0) == +0
```

You'll get the same behavior in all modern languages when dealing with raw floating point numbers.

Comment: This is a great answer. Your explanation for `+0 + +0 = +0` does not directly answer the first question of the OP, where they wrote `+0 + -0 = +0` (not the negative sign).

Comment: (I guess `(+0) + (-0) = (+0) - (+0) = (+0)`, while `(-0) + (+0) = (-0) - (-0) = (-0)` but since `(+0) == (-0)` the two sums are equal, thus conserving the commutativity.)

Comment: @chiccodoro I truncated the first part of the quoted pseudo-code for better clarity.

Comment: sorry, I think you got me wrong. Your equation was a helpful explanation for +0 + +0, but not for +0 + -0 (adding a *negative zero* to a positive zero). After truncating this is still the case.

Comment: @chiccodoro: I tried to answer the missing point: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28883018/656988

Answer (score 2):

IEEE754 specifies a *signed zero*. That is, -0.0 and +0.0 are represented individually.

They are *defined* to compare true on equality.

Java is implementing this correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you asked "*how does Java decide the sign in addition and substraction*" and it was left unanswered so far.

IEEE754 does not seem to completely define the result: it just says:

> [...] the sign of a sum, or of a difference *x − y* regarded as a sum
>   *x + (−y)*, differs from at most one of the addends’ signs; [...]
>   These rules shall apply even when operands or results are zero or infinite.

(§6.3; text unchanged between revisions.) I understand that it means that `b - c` is `+0.`, `c + c` or `c - b` are `-0.`, but `b + c` and `c + b` (and `b - b`, and `c - c`) could be either `+0.` or `-0.`.

**[Edited part]**

Then IEEE754 adds:

> When the sum of two operands with opposite signs (or the difference of two operands with like signs) is exactly zero, the sign of that sum (or difference) shall be + in all rounding modes except toward ─∞ [...]

which should apply here too; and it constraints the sign of the expressions `b + c`, `c + b`, `b - b`, and `c - c`, to be `+0.` (since the rounding mode is never toward ─∞ in Java.)

Sorry that I missed that part of first reading. And indeed it seems to be fully specified by the IEEE 754 standard.

**[End of edition]**

On the other hand, Java specification ([§6.5 about *dadd*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.dadd)) is more precise, and states

> [...] The sum of two zeroes of opposite sign is positive zero.

Javascript ([§11.6.3 of version 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.3)) has a similar specification:

> [...] The sum of two nonzero finite values of the same magnitude and opposite sign is `+0`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some interesting observations on wikipedia 
  [Signed_zero Properties_and_handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Properties_and_handling)

In Java, to distinguish between IEEE 754 Positive Zero and IEEE 754 Negative Zero you can use the Double wrapper.

```
System.out.println((0.0==-0.0)); // prints out TRUE (as expected)
System.out.println(new Double(0.0).
         equals(new Double(-0.0))); // prints out FALSE
```

Also `java.lang.Math.min(-0.0,+0.0)` evaluates to `-0.0` and `java.lang.Math.max(-0.0,+0.0)` evaluates to `+0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the other answers that you can figure out the sign of zero either by checking `1.0 / myzero > 0.0` or by checking whether the number is bitwise zero, as in `Double.doubleToLongBitz(myzero) != 0` (true for `-0`, false for `+0`.)