# Why does division be negative zero returns positive infinity in Java?

Tags: java

When I divide a positive double by negative zero, the result returns positive infinity.

```
double d = 10.0 / -0;
```

But when I divide a negative double by positive zero, the result returns negative infinity.

```
double d = -10.0 / 0;
```

Can someone explain this behavior ? Shouldn't the both operations return negative infinity ?

Comment: That's a good catch. I did not check that with 0.0.

Comment: I think I know why the code will not throw an ArithmeticException because we are dealing with double data type. I am curious to know as to why we have this weird behavior when dividing with negative zero.

Comment: Have you checked the [second answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137989/java-division-by-zero-doesnt-throw-an-arithmeticexception-why#answer-14138032)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there isn't actually a negative *integer* zero in the Java specification due to the two's complement representation used, which is clarified in answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893756/is-there-a-signed-zero-integer-in-java). Therefore `-0` as an integer is just an unsigned `0`.

If you run this test with floating point numbers, it performs as you expected:

```
double d = 10.0 / -0.0; // -Infinity
```

So the issue isn't with your logic, just your test.

Comment: But why does `-0.0 == 0.0` return `true` ?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24238293/7804477) explains if anyone has the above same doubt.